# Pass a context as a parameter in .net core, c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the current situation, I have this base context from which I'm inheriting other two contexts

```
namespace AutoAttendant.Data
{
    public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<LockStatus> LockResult { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AutoAttendantContext : BaseDbContext
    {
        internal AutoAttendantContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public AutoAttendantContext(DbContextOptions<AutoAttendantContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }

    public partial class ReadOnlyAutoAttendantContext : BaseDbContext
    {
        internal ReadOnlyAutoAttendantContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public ReadOnlyAutoAttendantContext(DbContextOptions<ReadOnlyAutoAttendantContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And I wanted to used this context as a parameter here

```
namespace AutoAttendant.API.ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, Version version, **BaseDbContext context**)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<**context**>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(version), op =>
            {
                op.EnableRetryOnFailure();
            }));

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to pass it correctly because is used a type in the `AddDbContextPool`, any ideas?

How could I use this with my inherited contexts when I called the AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration

```
services.AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new Version(5, 7), AutoAttendantContext);

services.AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ReadOnlyConnection"), new Version(5, 7), ReadOnlyAutoAttendantContext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your context type generic:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration<TContext>(
        this IServiceCollection services, 
        string connectionString, 
        Version version)
        where TContext : BaseDbContext
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<TContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(version), op =>
        {
            op.EnableRetryOnFailure();
        }));

        return services;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One question How should I use this with my inherited contexts when I call the AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration


services.AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new Version(5, 7), AutoAttendantContext);
                services.AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ReadOnlyConnection"), new Version(5, 7), ReadOnlyAutoAttendantContext);

Comment: Given that you don't appear to use an actual instance of the context, I changed my answer to remove that parameter. You would use, for example, `AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration services.AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration<AutoAttendantContext>(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new Version(5, 7));`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One last question, this "where TContext : BaseDbContext" is like saying TContext is inheriting from BaseDbContext? Is an inheritance or what it is called? I need to study this please

Comment: It's called a *generic constraint*. It says, when code gets compiled, there should be an error if someone tries calling this method using a generic type argument that _doesn't_ inherit `BaseDbContext`. It also allows you to do things with `TContext` in this method that you could typically do with a type that inherits `BaseDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a type parameter instead:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddPomeloDataSourceConfiguration<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, Version version)
{
    services.AddDbContextPool<TContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(version), op =>
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much!